# batch find command not working

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr

does anyone know why this would not work (Windows 7, batch script)?

```
C:\testing>FINDSTR /R /N "^.*$" test.txt | FIND /C ":"

FIND: `/C': No such file or directory
FIND: `:': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Works for me too.  Do you have `find` overridden somehow with another `find` in your path?  Do you have a DOSKEY macro overriding `find`?
What do you get when you run `where find.exe`?

Comment: @CookieButter - yes.Looks like an error produced by the unix `find`. @Fractal - what is the output of `find -h`  ?

Comment: find-h : 'find-h' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: sorry, missed the space

Comment: find -h: find: unknown predicate `-h'

Comment: definitely not the windows command .Try with `FINDSTR /R /N "^.*$" test.txt | %windir\system32\%FIND /C ":"`

Comment: the out put of windows `find -h` is `FIND: Parameter format not correct` . May be you are using unix port that requires `-H` (upper case) to show it's help or `--help` or `-help`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try with :

`FINDSTR /R /N "^.*$" test.txt | %windir%\system32\FIND.exe /C ":"`

Meanwhile with:

`for %f in (find.exe) do @echo %~dpfnx$PATH:f`

(double `%` for batch file) you can see which `FIND.EXE` will be executed.

Comment: okay ... I have cygwin installed so the unix find command must be interfering with the batch command like npocmaka and cookie stated.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\find.exe` was executed! Thanks.