# spark launch : find version

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark

My environment is Windows 7, and scala 2.11.4 installed (works well), Java 1.8

I have tried spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4 and spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4 and each time I put

```
bin\spark-shell.cmd
```

I just got the error from Windows:

```
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.
```

Is there anything I ignored here?

Thank you so much.

updated: (from spark-class2.cmd)

```
C:\Users\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4>for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('java -version 2>&1 | find "version"') do set jversi on=%i
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.
```

and if I try java -version, it seems working on java side

```
C:\Users\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4>java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What happens when you run spark-shell?

Comment: Can you change your spark-submit2.cmd file so that @echo on instead of off. Then paste your echo output?

Comment: @JustinPihony : I got the same result by only bin\spark-shell.

Comment: Yah, I never looked too close at what these scripts did until now, but it seems that my second comment will be more helpful. I think you have an environment variable that is messed up.

Comment: @JustinPihony : because the system here does not allow me to post whole thing, allow me to put the last messages: C:\Users\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4>cmd /V /E /C C:\Users\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4\bin\..\bin\spark-clas
s.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main  spark-shell
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Oops, I didn't go far enough. turn echo back off on the spark-submit2.cmd and turn it on for spark-class2.cmd. THAT is the last redirection :)...although it calls into other files...but here's to hoping :). Also, you can edit your original post to post the entire thing

Comment: You may have to turn on echo for compute-classpath.cmd also...

Comment: @JustinPihony : Appreciate, here is what I got : 'C:\Users\spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4>for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('java -version 2>&1 | find "version"') do set jversi
on=%i
find: 'version': No such file or directory
else was unexpected at this time. '

Comment: Just updated the original post. It seems the root cause is the **'java -version 2>&1 | find "version"** ?

Comment: What happens when you run : `for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do echo %i`

Comment: hmm... same result : find: 'version': No such file or directory

Comment: Try the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642548/batch-find-command-not-working                        `for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| %windir%\system32\FIND.exe "version"') do echo %i`

Comment: Oh, and are you running this in cygwin as the OP from the related question?

Comment: Nope, maybe that is something I missed?

Comment: No to what? The second for that I posted to test, or no to cygwin

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I did not use Cygwin. And adding 2^>^&1 gave the same "no version found" result.

Comment: OK, can you go to your windows directory/system32 and see if you have find.exe

Comment: Hi, the c:\windows\system\FIND.exe does exist in my system. And per what you mentioned 3 hours ago, **for /F "tokens=3" %i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| %windir%\system32\FIND.exe "version"') do echo %I ** did work, and I got **"1.8.0_31"**. _You are the man!!_

Comment: when I put the modification directly, it ran well. However, it needs the %I modified to %%I in the file to run. and then the next command line got the problem with their % ...

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem. Here is my solution.

I have cygwin installed and PATH system variable pointed to C:\cygwin64\bin\ where there is a find.exe.

Therefore, the line in spark-class2.cmd

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do set jversion=%%i
```

did not use the proper "find" executable.

Changing this line to this

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| C:\Windows\System32\find.exe "version"') do set jversion=%%i
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helps. In my local it's the git folder in the PATH that has a find command which mask the system's. I use 'where find' command to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize the codes there was trying to figure out the version of JVM, and since I know it 1.8.0_31. Here is my silly solution:

```
rem Set JAVA_OPTS to be able to load native libraries and to set heap size
rem for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| %windir%\system32\FIND.exe "version"') do echo %%i
rem for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in ("%jversion:~1,-1%") do set jversion=%%i
rem if "%jversion%" geq "1.8.0" (
  set JAVA_OPTS=%OUR_JAVA_OPTS% -Xms%OUR_JAVA_MEM% -Xmx%OUR_JAVA_MEM%
rem ) else (
rem   set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m %OUR_JAVA_OPTS% -Xms%OUR_JAVA_MEM% -Xmx%OUR_JAVA_MEM%
rem )
```

and I think the Spark team needs to work on this

rem    Set JAVA_OPTS to be able to load native libraries and to set heap size
     for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| %windir%\system32\FIND.exe "version"') do echo %%i
     for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" **%%i in ("%jversion:~1,-1%") do set jversion=%%i**

Comment: "I think the Spark team needs to work on this" - If you want the Spark team to have this issue on their radar, you can [report it on the official Spark JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/).

Comment: Actually, I went ahead and reported this issue for you here: [SPARK-6084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6084)

Comment: Duplicate; I even think it's resolved for 1.3 by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5396 I wonder if you can try the patch in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4428 to see if it fixes it? if so, that helps closed down another duplicate.

Comment: I had the same problem on my Windows 7 64bit. I was just about to give up. Then I tried the *spark-shell.cmd* in **Powershell**, and it worked...I think the developer worked with powershell, and expects it to work with cmd as well.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found the root cause for this issue. Your JAVA_HOME is not set correctly, Please set this in environment variable correctly. Make sure your java path is not containing any space.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem. We figured that it had something to do with java. So we re-installed java-sdk (1.7) and checked if path and JAVA_HOME are properly set. After that spark-shell.cmd and spark-submit.cmd worked fine.

Platform: Windows 8.