# How do I start Spark's Shell on Window's 8.1?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I keep trying to get the Spark shell running to no avail.

## OS: Windows 8.1

## Spark: 1.3.1

## Java: 8

Downloaded both prepackaged and unpackaged variants (unpackaged variant built by maven and simple build tool). I've attempted to resolve my issue three different ways to no avail.

1) From my Spark Directory, I attempt to start its shell with variants of `spark-shell.cmd` or `.\bin\spark-shell.cmd`.

I consistently get an error along these lines:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Knowing a possible whitespace error when I see one, I've attempted variants of my command with quotes, full paths, etc.  No results thus far.

2) Next, I've tried simply moving my spark directory to highest level of my harddrive  (C:\ \spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6).

With whitespace eliminated as a possible issue, my error messages now fall along these lines:

> find: 'version': No such file or directory
>   else was unexpected at this time.

3) I've tried to invoke Spark through Scala somehow (as some documents and [screencasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL-x35fyliRwhKT-NpTKprPW1bkbdDcTTW&t=356&v=bWorBGOFBWY) given the impression).  I can confirm that Scala (2.11.6) is properly configured within my environment variables. Its shell works correctly.

If there's supposedly a command to make it start the Spark shell, I'm listening. Current attempts through Scala is another dead end.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747795/spark-launch-find-version ?

Comment: After looking at it, I have found a solution that works for the copy of spark stored high upon the C Drive.. 
Within the spark directory that is stored at C:/
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| C:\Windows\System32\find.exe "version"') do set jversion=%%i

Comment: Thank you for your reference. I have found a solution that works for the copy of spark stored high upon the C Drive.


At spark-class2.cmd:

From:
=
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do set jversion=%%i
=

Change:
=
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| C:\Windows\System32\find.exe "version"') do set jversion=%%i
=

Answer (score 4):

In this file `bin\spark-class2.cmd` find the line

```
set RUNNER="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
```

and replace it with (remove the ")

```
set RUNNER=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
```

Answer (score 2):

- Moving Spark directory under C:\ worked for me.*(C:\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6)*.
- I also updated the system's PATH variable for find.exe

Answer (score 2):

To solve the `C:\Program is not recognized`, change `C:\Program Files` to `C:\Progra~1`, which is an alias for `C:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from moving Spark & Scala to C:\ , I had to move java installation to C:\ as  well

Answer (score 0):

I just  attempted to install Spark On my Windows 8.1 laptop. I followed the instructions given in the Safari online Video titled "Apache Spark with Scala":
[Apache Spark With Scala](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-spark-with/9781787129849/)
After following the simple instructions the "spark-shell" command refused to work at all. I tried everything, reinstalling, changing directory names ... blah blah. I even attempted to rewrite the maze of intertwinning shell scripts that bring it up. All with no success. Finally I tried to install an earlier release.
I installed the "2.1.0:" release instead of the 2.1.1.
EVERYTHING WORKED THEN.
This seems to imply that the windows .cmd commands are totally broken in the 2.1.1 release:
[image: from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html]