# How to run Apache Spark in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I have downloaded the usb to start using spark from the [spark summit website](https://spark-summit.org/2014/training). However I can't get it running on my Windows 8.1 test machine.

```
c:\Users\User\Documents\Apache.Spark\usb\spark\bin>spark-shell
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Environment:

- Windows 8.1
- Java 7 Update 79 for 64 bits (jdk-7u79-windows-x64)

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons. Can you use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747795/spark-launch-find-version and its comments to see if you can help track down the issue a little more further into the launch scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it fixed.

My problem was that JAVA_HOME was pointing to the wrong location.

Check the your **JAVA_HOME environment variable**.

In my case `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`

The cause of this issue was that I installed a new version of JDK and removed the previous installation but JAVA_HOME was pointing to the old environment which was missing.